# How to access root panel from widget in Google Web Toolkit (GWT)

Tags: gwt

I have an entry point which handles
My main layout including menu, header and etc.Also it
has  rootpanel.get().add (login)
at the end to show the login page (uibinder)

Login.java uses uibinder and it works perfectly using RPC with server side class and I have got a reponse from database for user authentication which has been living on Google cloud sql.

I am trying to redirect user after
Login to the home page but my problem is I can not access Root panel from Login.java. 
Basically I want to change the root panel from widget and redirect the user to the appropriate page based on log in result.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is preventing use of RootPanel.get() in your Login class? Can't you just use `RootPanel.get().clear()` followed by `RootPanel.get().add()`?

Comment: You may want to read about Activities and Places design pattern for GWT. It offers a lot of functionality for navigation, history management, etc., that you do not need to implement yourself. Read more at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `RootPanel.get().clear()` followed by `RootPanel.get().add()` from anywhere in your code (including from your Login class). Note that it is generally better to use `RootLayoutPanel` instead of `RootPanel`, and I would take Andrei's advice and take a look at activities and places.